# maxima fails for very simple equality (is equal)

Tags: precision, equals, fractions, maxima

I have a very simple numeric comparison for which maxima is failing. I turned on verbose mode and debugmode but not able to see any additional detail. Is there something I need to specify (I tried different values for fpprec, but no use).

```
(%i2) is(equal(18225979/30454181, 0.5984721441039565));

(%o2)                                false
```

As long as arguments are equal up to 12 digits after decimal, I want maxima to return true. Thanks in advance for your solutions and suggestions.
-Breddy

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is something like `is(abs(x - y)/abs(y) < 1e-12)` where `x` and `y` are the numbers in question.

`is(equal(x, y))` is implemented as `is(ratsimp(x - y) = 0)`. This differs in a subtle way from a simple test for a number of digits. My advice is to test the absolute relative difference as suggested above.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I actually do not have x and y directly available. I am receiving them from a Perl program and invoking Maxima.What I received was [c:5;b:90;a:2; (sin(abs(-5)*1.7*mod((5+a*100),5))-7)/(20+5-4*abs(-1))+b*20-100+(a**2+b**2+2*a*b);] and [10163.66666666667]. There can be symbols without values. My code has to find equality.

Comment: OK. What is the larger problem you are trying to solve? By the way, it helps to write code within `backticks like this` so that it is clearer to the reader.

Comment: Simplest description of the problem I am tasked to solve is: find if *any* two expressions are equal (symbolically or numerically). Example: `x=(a+b)^2; y=(a^2+b^2+2*a*b); is(equal(x,y));` I receive them from another module along with a list of variables and their numerical values (which could be empty). These expressions could have trigonometry functions, built-in functions, user defined functions, variables, and constants. If beneficial, I can try multiple methods repeatedly (simplify, factor, equal, or other; or combinations; I am not constrained on performance - yet).

Comment: The reason I simplified the question to only numerical values is that I have not yet seen Maxima failing on purely symbolic comparisons. My failed test cases so far are numerical comparisons only. I might see failures with more complex expressions, but if Maxima fails for the simplest cases, I might have to find a different solution (Perl, Java, python, or other commercial software).

Comment: Larger problem: comparing sets of few thousands of these expressions will identify equivalent designs (equivalent in a defined sense), with different characteristics. I am hoping maxima has enough features (I am relatively new to this tool) to find equality of expressions, even if not as straight forward as `is(equal(x,y))`.

Comment: I'll write more later, but for the moment just a question. Are you working on evaluating homework problems or something like that? If so, there is an existing system called STACK (which uses Maxima) which has resolved many of the problems which arise. I think a web search for STACK and Moodle should find it.

Comment: Thank you for the STACK info. My requirement is more general purpose than STACK's ( `simplify(student_answer - teacher_answer) = 0` ), which should be usable to compare mathematical models containing large sets of expressions as well.